# Pythagorean theorem and orthocenter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, pythagorean-triples

> Point $H$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$. Let $AD$ and $CM$ be the altitudes. Show that $BM^2-BD^2=HD^2-HM^2$.

By Pythagorean theorem:
1) $\triangle BCM \rightarrow BM^2=BC^2-CM^2$ and 2) $\triangle ABD \rightarrow BD^2-AB^2-AD^2$. How to approach the problem further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write Pytagorean theorem in right triangles which includes also the point $H$, say $HCD$ and $HAM$.

Better, try $HBM$ and $HBD$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! From $\triangle HAM \rightarrow AH^2=AM^2+MH^2$ and $\triangle HCD \rightarrow CH^2=DH^2+CD^2$. How to use this further?

Comment: Seems that HAM and HCD are not usefull for the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the response! We have $BH^2=BM^2+MH^2=BD^2+DH^2$.

Comment: $BM^2+MH^2=BD^2+DH^2 \Rightarrow BM^2-BD^2=DH^2-MH^2$.

Comment: I see. So the point was to write Pythagorean theorem in right triangles that include the point $H$.